# if and ifnot knockout statement in the same line

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

Hi guys i am trying to do a knockout statement which changes certain factors if it is classed as true or false. My problem is i need a if and a ifnot statement in the same line to output the correct result.

Example codes:

```
   <!-- ko if: User().loggedin --> 

                <li><a href="#"><p class="Score">1</p><p style="display:none;"
                    >First</p></a></li> 
                            <!--/ko-->
```

Now i need a ifnot statement within that statement as it has a couple of different ways it can go.

```
<!-- ko ifnot: Goal -->
```

So how do i mix them both up so they can be outputed on the same line. Example below (which i know doesnt work.) but may get you to understand completely what i want.

```
<!-- ko if: User().loggedin --> 
 <!-- ko ifnot: Goal -->    
                    <li><a href="#"><p class="Score">1</p><p style="display:none;"
                        >First</p></a></li> 
                                <!--/ko-->
<!--/ko-->
```

All the observable's work fine.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Other than massively-confusing indentation, your second example is fine; here it is with the confusion removed:

```
<!-- ko if: User().loggedin --> 
    <!-- ko ifnot: Goal -->    
                    <li><a href="#"><p class="Score">1</p><p style="display:none;"
                        >First</p></a></li> 
    <!--/ko-->
<!--/ko-->
```

alternately:

```
<!-- ko if: User().loggedin && !Goal() -->    
                    <li><a href="#"><p class="Score">1</p><p style="display:none;"
                        >First</p></a></li> 
                                <!--/ko-->
<!--/ko-->
```

...assuming `Goal` is an observable (remove the `()` if not).